# Is possible to use Hostinger to hosting a Julia app developed with Genie builder?

Tags: julia, hosting, genie

I have developed a Julia web app with Genie Builder. I would like to load it on my Hostinger website, is that possible?

I tried uploading the files generated by Genie builder but only some HTML is displayed without any interactivity.